# Practicando platzigram en Javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, gulp

Estoy realizando el proyecto *Platzigram* de Platzi_ para practicar *Javascript* y demás. Al momento de usar el **package.json** para automatizar tareas con `<script>` no me funciona al ejecutar el comando `npm start` y que se ejecuten las tareas *gulp watch* y ***node server.js***, solo se ejecuta una sola de ellas y la que está primero. Dejaré el **package.json** y el *gulpfile* para que me digan si algo está mal y aclaro que lo estoy ejecutando en entorno *Windows*.

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "photogram",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Ver y compartir fotos",
  "main": "server.js",
  "keywords": [
    "photogram",
    "javascript",
    "fotos"
  ],
  "author": "Christian Carballo",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "materialize-css": "^0.98.2",
    "page": "^1.7.1",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify": "^14.3.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "scripts":{
    "build": "gulp",
    "start":"gulp watch & node server.js"
  }
}
```

El *gulpfile*:

```
var gulp= require("gulp");
var sass=require("gulp-sass");
var rename=require("gulp-rename");
var babel= require("babelify");
var browserify=require("browserify");
var source=require("vinyl-source-stream");
var watchify= require("watchify")

gulp.task("styles", function(){
    gulp
        .src("index.scss")
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(rename("app.css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("public"));
})

gulp.task("assets",function(){
    gulp
        .src("assets/*")
        .pipe(gulp.dest("public"));
})

function compile(watch){
    var bundle=watchify(browserify("./src/index.js"));

    function rebundle() {
        bundle
            .transform(babel)
            .bundle()
            .pipe(source("index.js"))
            .pipe(rename("app.js"))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("public"));

    }

    if (watch) {
        bundle.on("update", function(){
            console.log("-->Bundling...");
            rebundle();
        });
    }

    rebundle();
}

gulp.task("build", function(){
    return compile()

});

gulp.task("watch", function(){ return compile(true); });
gulp.task("default", ["styles", "assets","build"]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En los sistemas basados en Unix se suele utilizar el símbolo `&` para correr dos o más tareas en paralelo como en el caso del script

`"start": "gulp watch & node server.js"`

pero si estás intentando correr este código en Windows o quieres hacer algo que funcione igual en multiples sistemas operativos puedes probar soluciones como [npm-run-all](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all) y sustituir por

`"gulp-watch": "gulp watch"
"start-server": "node server.js"
"start": "npm-run-all --parallel gulp-watch start-server"`

Comment: muchas gracias! funciona y si, intuia que el error podia estar en el hecho de ejecutar el comando en windows y no en linux, soy nuevo y recien empiezo hay muchas cosas que debo aprender!